# How to get item with given id and given username from array in MongoDB in Node

Tags: node.js, mongodb, typescript

I have such a schema and would like to get the user object for given userName and _id:

```
{
"_id":ObjectId("5cb7267d7ea090083be865c6"),
"name": test,
"users":[
    {
        "userName": "user1",
        "role": "admin"
    },
    {
        "userName": "user2",
        "role": "basic"
    }]
},
{
"_id":ObjectId("5cb7267d7ea090083be865c7"),
"name": test,
"users":[
    {
        "userName": "user3",
        "role": "admin"
    },
    {
        "userName": "user4",
        "role": "basic"
    }]
}
```

I have tried the following query, based on the official Mongo documentation:

```
db.users.find( { _id: new ObjectId(5cb7267d7ea090083be865c6) },
             { users: { $elemMatch: { userName: 'user1' } } } )
```

I am using typescript and get the following error message and not sure how to proceed:

```
 Argument of type '{ users: { $elemMatch: { userName: string; }; }; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'FindOneOptions'.
 Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'users' does not exist in type 'FindOneOptions'.
```

Comment: `find` returns the whole document.  If you need only a single subdocument of `users` array you need to use https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/aggregation/

Comment: That's a typescript compilation error and not an error thrown by MongoDB itself. `db.users.find()` does not look like the NodeJS driver form, which would be more like `db.collection('users').find()`. What driver are you actually using? And where did the typescript definitions for this library come from? Because I suspect they are incorrect, or at least not compatible with the actual library being used.

Comment: If this were the NodeJS driver, then it really should be `db.collection('users').find({ _id: new ObjectId(5cb7267d7ea090083be865c6) }).project({ users: { $elemMatch: { userName: 'user1' } } })` if you just want projection of the matching element and of course empty arrays where that condition for projection does not match.

Answer (score 0):

I think you accidentally added unnecessary braces and passed `{users: {...}}` as [options argument](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.find). That's why your code doesn't compile. Try this:

```js
db.users.find( {
 _id: new ObjectId(5cb7267d7ea090083be865c6),
 users: { $elemMatch: { userName: 'user1' } }
});
```